# MFC: How dock multiple windows in same position?

Tags: c++, mfc, docking

I have mfc application with docking windows, I need to place multiple docking windows in same place ( one on each other ).
When I dock child windows this way

```
DockPane(&m_wndNotify, AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_BOTTOM);
DockPane(&m_wndOutput, AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_BOTTOM);
```

they dock in bottom of mainframe , but one after other, not in same place.
On runtime I can move windows and place them one on each other, but how can do this on beginning of application ?

Answer (score 2):

So I [found](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983712.aspx) the way to place one docking window to other

```
m_wndOutput.AttachToTabWnd(&m_wndNotify, DM_STANDARD, TRUE);
```